# Finding Non Matching ID

Tags: mysql, sql, join, match

I have two tables, called "One" and "Two", they are both the same, table "One" has some IDs that are not there in Table "Two". but when i run this mysql Query, i can not get those non-matching values.

```
select count(bene) from one where bene not in (select bene from two);
```

And the result is Zero. so how do i get the non-matching values from Table one that are not there in table Two?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select count(*) from one a where not exists (select * from two b where a.bene=b.bene)
```

Comment: Thank you, it works, but may i know why didn't my query work, since it looks fine too. and could you please elaborate on this query(yours), or tell me what type of query it is, so that i can search and learn it.
Thanks :)

Comment: Ur query is just fine.I have no idea about the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can perform a left join and find only values that do not exist in second table. Below query is assuming that `bene` is your ID column:

```
SELECT one.*
FROM one 
    LEFT JOIN two ON one.bene = two.bene
WHERE two.bene IS NULL
```

or if you need just the count

```
SELECT COUNT(one.bene)
FROM one 
    LEFT JOIN two ON one.bene = two.bene
WHERE two.bene IS NULL
```

When performing a Left join you find all values in table `one` with corresponding values in table `two`. If there is no match all table `two` values will be `NULL`.

Then as a second step you use `WHERE` to filter only rows that have `NULL` for table `two`. This way you find all records in table `one` that do not have matching records in table `two`.

Comment: the First query work so much faster. and the result of yours and that query is the same. thanks